Are cost and cast being regularized?
I watch a fair few videos about video games on youtube, and a while back I started to notice that many people in those videos used "costed" and "casted" for the past tenses of "cost" and "cast.
I'm familiar with the use of "costed" to mean "having a cost assigned", e.g. "The pineapple was costed at $10 per kilo."
But not in "The pineapple costed $10 per kilo."
I'm not familiar with any traditional use of "casted", and as I write this, it does get the red squiggles of disapproval.
I might add that the vast majority of videos I noticed this in are of native English speakers. Mainly from the US if memory serves.
So I started to wonder: Given that every language is constantly changing, including English, are these two verbs (and maybe others I just didn't notice) becoming regular?
At least for "cast", this would be very plausible to me. I imagine the much wider availability and use of (broad)casting technology, as well as the use of the term in video (and board) games have greatly increased the use of the word "cast" in the last few decades.
I've tried looking this up with various search engines, but unfortunately I only found a mountain of teaching / learning material about irregular verbs.
I'd be delighted to read your thoughts and especially read any studies on the matter if they exist.
Cheers!

I'd say usages such as 'The play has already been casted' / 'He was casted as Sauron' are becoming standard.  I've not found dictionary support for this. And in fact Wiktionary has the caveat 'nonstandard' for casted  to cover all senses of 'cast'. //  'Casted' also means 'belonging to a caste'.

Over my dead body are those usages acceptable. But that's kind of the way language goes, us oldies die off, the youngies (who are by then the middle-agies) see their youthful usages become accepted, and then the new generation commit abominations of their own devising.  Return to the beginning and continue reading ...

Some specific examples would be good, to see the context, country of origin, etc.

"having a cost assigned" - that is priced - the pricer is the one that assigns. Costed would be having a cost researched or estimated or allotted. As far as I know, it is only used as a phrasal verb.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88872/which-one-is-correct-cost-or-costed#:~:text=However%2C%20if%20you%20use%20'cost,(out)%20at%20%242.5%20million.

[a fair few? a fair number] Cast and cost only have that form. costed is very specific to accounting but even there is rarely used. casted is wrong.

Unfortunately I can't remember a specific example right now. It's one of those things one notices in the moment without making a note of it. I'll try to remember posting a link if I find an example in future.
